# NSRegularExpression: Proper regex for parsing d=4,b=5,o=63?

Tags: ios, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression to parse the following:

```
d=4,b=5,o=63
```

such that I can get the letters and the numbers out. Each letter has an allowed series of numbers.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
(?:(d)=(1|2|4|8|16|32))|(?:(o)=(5|6|7|8))
```

However, this gets me some weird results. In particular, I get the following results using the code below.

What confuses me is that I get these out-of-range ranges, and they're not consistent. For example, in match #1, the out-of-ranges are #3 and #4, but in match #2, they the out-of-ranges are #1 and #2.

Seems to me 1) I'm using a broken expression, 2) this NSRegularExpression is either buggy or 3) something is wrong out of my understanding.

Any help?

```
2012-01-20 11:01:56.027 TestRegex[95678:f803] -------------------------------
2012-01-20 11:01:56.027 TestRegex[95678:f803] Number of matches: 2
2012-01-20 11:01:56.028 TestRegex[95678:f803] Number of ranges = 5
2012-01-20 11:01:56.029 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  0:  0  3 | d=4
2012-01-20 11:01:56.030 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  1:  0  1 | d
2012-01-20 11:01:56.030 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  2:  2  1 | 4
2012-01-20 11:01:56.031 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  3: 2147483647  0 | <outside range>
2012-01-20 11:01:56.032 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  4: 2147483647  0 | <outside range>
2012-01-20 11:01:56.032 TestRegex[95678:f803] Number of ranges = 5
2012-01-20 11:01:56.033 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  0:  4  3 | o=5
2012-01-20 11:01:56.034 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  1: 2147483647  0 | <outside range>
2012-01-20 11:01:56.035 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  2: 2147483647  0 | <outside range>
2012-01-20 11:01:56.036 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  3:  4  1 | o
2012-01-20 11:01:56.037 TestRegex[95678:f803] Range  4:  6  1 | 5
```

The parse code:

```
NSString *pat = regexTextField.text;
NSString *str = stringTextField.text;

NSError *err;
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pat
                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                      error:&err];

NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
if (err != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err.localizedFailureReason);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err.localizedRecoverySuggestion);
    return;
}

NSUInteger n = [re numberOfMatchesInString:str
                                   options:0
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

NSLog(@"Number of matches: %u", n);

NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:str 
                               options:0 
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSLog(@"Number of ranges = %d", match.numberOfRanges);
    for (int c = 0; c < match.numberOfRanges; ++c) {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:c];
        NSString *matchStr;
        if (range.location >= str.length) {
            matchStr = @"<outside range>";
        } else {
            matchStr = [str substringWithRange:range];
        }
        NSLog(@"Range %2d: %2d %2d | %@", c, range.location, range.length, matchStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try this regex : `([a-z])=([0-9]+)`. It matches a single letter, followed by an equal sign, then a number. Two capture groups to store values.
Get all matches, then in the first matching group, you've got the letter, in the second the number.

So the regex you have is surely complicated, but no, the implementation works.
`-(NSRange)rangeAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;` returns the *entire* match range when given `0`, the ranges for capture groups follow. In the example below, you get the letter with the range at index `1` and the number at index `2`.

```
NSString *str = stringTextField.text;
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([a-z])=([0-9]+)"
                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                      error:&err];
NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:str 
                               options:0 
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange capture1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; // first capture group
    NSRange capture2 = [match rangeAtIndex:2]; // second one
    NSString *letter = [str substringWithRange:capture1];
    NSInteger number = [[str substringWithRange:capture2] integerValue];
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT :**

Coming back to your example, there are always 5 ranges : the entire match range at index 0, and four ranges for capture groups (`(d)`, `([1248]|16|32)`, `(o)`, `([5678])`) in order respectively from index 1 to 4. Ranges have to be handled differently so that the second time when you match `o=6`, capture group range indexes are now `3` and `4`. This can be done by testing range's `location` against `NSNotFound`.

```
NSString *str = @"d=4,b=5,o=63";
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:(d)=([1248]|16|32))|(?:(o)=([5678]))"
                                //    ^   ^                  ^   ^
                                //    1   2                  3   4
                         options:NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace
                           error:NULL];
NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:str 
                               options:0 
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
NSLog(@"Number of matches : %lu", [matches count]);
for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSLog(@"Number of ranges : %lu", match.numberOfRanges);
    NSLog(@"Globally matched from %lu, length = %lu", match.range.location, match.range.length);
    NSUInteger i = 1;
    NSRange capture1 = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
    NSRange capture2 = [match rangeAtIndex:i+1];
    while(capture1.location == NSNotFound) {
        i += 2;
        capture1 = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
        capture2 = [match rangeAtIndex:i+1];            
    }
    NSLog(@"Matched from %lu, length = %lu", capture1.location, capture1.length);
    NSLog(@"Matched from %lu, length = %lu", capture2.location, capture2.length);
    NSString *letter = [str substringWithRange:capture1];
    NSInteger number = [[str substringWithRange:capture2] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%@ = %ld", letter, number);
}
```

> 2012-01-21 17:04:02.845 TestApp[3481:707] Number of matches : 2
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.846 TestApp[3481:707] Number of ranges : 5
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.846 TestApp[3481:707] Globally matched from 0, length = 3
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.847 TestApp[3481:707] Matched from 0, length = 1
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.847 TestApp[3481:707] Matched from 2, length = 1
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.848 TestApp[3481:707] d = 4
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.848 TestApp[3481:707] Number of ranges : 5
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.848 TestApp[3481:707] Globally matched from 8, length = 3
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.849 TestApp[3481:707] Matched from 8, length = 1
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.849 TestApp[3481:707] Matched from 10, length = 1
>   2012-01-21 17:04:02.850 TestApp[3481:707] o = 6

Ranges are always defined but not always valid, depending on if the parenthesis have captured something.

Comment: I tend to agree, but a small correction. `[match rangeAtIndex:0]` returns entire matched range, so it should be `[match rangeAtIndex:1]` and `[match rangeAtIndex:2]`.

Comment: No, the point of the more complex regex is to do qualification of the values as well. If the regex did not match, invalid values are present. If I only wanted to extract the letter and number, there are simpler ways.

Comment: @Ana - ok what are legal letters, and what are valid numbers for them ?

Comment: @Ana - strange indeed, I tried the same as you with various combinations. I also have invalid ranges for the second match (`o=6`). The entire match range is valid (location : 8, length : 3), but capturing groups ranges aren't. The regex matches `d=4` correctly though. I ended with `(?:(?:(d)=([1248]|16|32))|(?:(o)=([5678])))`.